# Retrieve the linked list of a lookup with JavaScript in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, lookup

I have two lists: Products and Suppliers.
In Products, i have 3 columns :

-Name of Product (single line of text)

-Supplier (lookup of Suppliers : Name of Supplier)

-Price (choice list)

In Suppliers, i have 3 columns too :

-Name of Supplier (single line of text)

-Product (lookup of Products : Name of Product)

-Category (choice list)

Actually, in the .js linked to Product (list), i'm using this code to get the informations of the list Suppliers

```
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Suppliers');
```

But it's hardcoded and i have to dynamise the code so i will be able to apply this code to other lists.

For example:

```
var NameOfList = "code to get the name of the list which is linked by the lookup (in my case it's the list Suppliers)";
var ColumnsOfList = "NameOfList.getAllColumns (in my case it's Name of Supplier, Product, Category)";
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(NameOfList);  

var txt = [];
txt.push('The list ' + NameOfList + ' has those columns : ');
for(i=0 ; i<ColumnsOfList.length ; i++){
  txt.push(ColumnsOfList[i]);
}
alert(txt);
```

It will display `The list Suppliers has those columns : Name of Supplier, Product, Category`.

So, i would like to know which code or function to use for retrieve the listname and columns of the list which is linked by lookup. In my case, i would like to get "Suppliers" as listname and "Name of Supplier, Product, Category" as columns name.

Can someone help me please ?

EDIT : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRa5v.png)

Comment: Using REST you can implement this requirement easily compared to JSOM approach.

Comment: I'm a beginner so i don't know lot of things like REST :/

Comment: To make it dynamic, Create custom config list, store the list name inside config list. Read it from there and pass it to your javascript code.

Comment: @BatBatsukh I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish based on your question as written. Do you just want to display the names of columns in a lookup list? Can you elaborate further in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the details of the lookup column by retrieving it from the field collection using `SPList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle()`, invoking `executeQueryAsync()`, and then examining the lookup column's schema XML (via the `SPField.get_schemaXml()` method).

From the column's schema XML you can grab the lookup column's source list and run another `executeQueryAsync()` to load up its field collection so you can get the names of all its fields.

Here's an example of how your code might appear.

```
var listName = "Products";
var lookupColumn = "Supplier";

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

// get a reference to the lookup field on the current list
var lookupField = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(lookupColumn);

 // queue up the lookup field for retrieval
 clientContext.load(lookupField);   
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      function(){ 

           // get the lookup list GUID from the lookup column's schema XML:
           var lookupListId = lookupField.get_schemaXml().match(/List=(.*?)(?!\S)/g)[0].match(/[^List="][^"]*/)[0];

           // get references to the lookup list and its field collection
           var lookupList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(lookupListId);
           var lookupListFields = lookupList.get_fields();

           // queue up the lookup list and field collection for retrieval
           clientContext.load(lookupList);
           clientContext.load(lookupListFields);
           clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
               function(){
                   var lookupListName = lookupList.get_title();
                   var fieldNames = [];

                   // enumerate through the field collection to get the field names
                   var fieldEnum = lookupListFields.getEnumerator();
                   while(fieldEnum.moveNext()){
                       var field = fieldEnum.get_current();
                       fieldNames.push(field.get_title());
                   }

                   doSomethingWithListAndFieldNames(lookupListName,fieldNames);

               },
               function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());}
          );
      },
      function(sender,args){ // onError
           alert(args.get_message());
      }
 );
```

Replace `doSomethingWithListAndFieldNames()` with your own function.

## Getting only the fields from the default view:

If you only want the fields that display in the default view of the lookup list, you need to do a little extra work to query the views of the lookup list and look for the default view, then get the view fields from that view.

```
var listName = "Products"; // original list title
var lookupColumn = "Supplier"; // lookup column name

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

// get a reference to the lookup field on the current list
var lookupField = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(lookupColumn);

// queue up the lookup field for retrieval
clientContext.load(lookupField);   
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      function(){ 
           // get the lookup list GUID from the lookup column's schema XML:
           var lookupListId = lookupField.get_schemaXml().match(/List=(.*?)(?!\S)/g)[0].match(/[^List="][^"]*/)[0];

           // get reference to the lookup list
           var lookupList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(lookupListId);

           // queue up the lookup list for retrieval
           clientContext.load(lookupList);
           clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
               function(){
                   var lookupListName = lookupList.get_title();

                   // get the views on the list
                   var views = lookupList.get_views();

                   // queue up the viewsfor retrieval
                   clientContext.load(views);
                   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                       function(){

                            // loop through the views until you find the default view
                            var viewEnum = views.getEnumerator();
                            while(viewEnum.moveNext()){
                                var view = viewEnum.get_current();
                                if(view.get_defaultView()){

                                     // retrieve the fields from the view
                                     var lookupListFields = view.get_viewFields();
                                     clientContext.load(lookupListFields);
                                     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                                         function(){
                                              var fieldNames = [];

                                              // enumerate through the field collection to get the field names
                                              var fieldEnum = lookupListFields.getEnumerator();
                                              while(fieldEnum.moveNext()){
                                                  fieldNames.push(fieldEnum.get_current());
                                              }
                                          
                                              doSomethingWithListAndFieldNames(lookupListName,fieldNames);

                                         },
                                         function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());}
                                     );
                                     break;
                                }                                
                            }
                       },
                       function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());});
               },
               function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());}
          );
      },
      function(sender,args){ // onError
           alert(args.get_message());
      }
 );
```

Comment: The code works but that gives me too much fields, how can i filter it to get only the columns name i need ?

Comment: @BatBatsukh You could hardcode it with the desired fields if you know which fields you need ahead of time. Otherwise, you could identify the built-in columns that you *don't* want and explicitly exclude those fields from being added to the `fieldNames` array while you're enumerating through the lookup list fields.

Comment: Is there a function or a soluce to select the columns which are displayed in the list ? For example, in my Suppliers list, i display 3 columns, Name of Supplier, Product, Category, is it possible to keep only those 3 fields in `fieldNames` or have i to hardcode this ? Cause when i don't apply filter, i have lot of fields like 30fields.

Comment: Oh, yes, you can get the view fields from the default view of the list object. I've updated my answer with the code for doing so.

Comment: That works perfectly ! But do you know why that doesn't dispaly "Title" but "LinkTitle" ? I edit my post and add the screen

Comment: There are a few different copies of the Title column. The one that just shows the title field as plain text is called "Title" internally, while the one that displays it as a link to the item's display form is called "LinkTitle"

Comment: So how can i get the "Title" ? Cause i apply filter with camlQuery so i need the right name of the column

Comment: You should be able to use LinkTitle in place of Title in your CAML query and have it return the same results.

Comment: Just one last thing, i can't use "LinkTitle" to display fields of "Title". For example `oListItem.get_item('Title')` works but `oListItem.get_item(LUFieldName[0])`, where "LUFieldName[0]" equals "LinkTitle", doesn't work

Comment: In the `load()` function you can to tell SharePoint to explicitly include certain columns in the results it sends back to you. Before calling `executeQueryAsync` you need to call `clientContext.load(oListItems,"Include(LinkTitle)");` (for a list item collection) or `clientContext.load(oListItem,"LinkTitle");` (for a single list item). You need to include all the fields that you want to have loaded, so if `fieldNames` is your array of fields, you could call `clientContext.load(oListItems, "Include("+fieldNames.join(",")+")");` or `clientContext.load(oListItem,fieldNames.join(","));`